# Function hdr.den(), problem with intervals of x axis

Tags: r, rstudio, axis

I have a problem with the function `hdr.den`, I can't modify the intervals of axis x, and the graphic is printed only with default values. My code is:

```
library(hdrcde)
dades <- data.frame(via = c("A-2", "A-2", "A-2"), pk = c(450, 450.2, 451), valor = c(3, 1, 2))
dens <- density(dades$pk, bw = 0.1)
nBreaks = 10
xaxpi <- c(trunc(min(dades$pk)), trunc(max(dades$pk)), nBreaks)

hdr <- hdr.den(round(dades$pk, 1), den = dens,
           xaxp = xaxpi, cex.axis = 0.6, las = 2,
           main = paste("Concentraciones relativas"))
```

Although I modify the variable `nBreaks`, the axis doesn't change:

[image]

I have also tried to completely delete the divisions of axis x, by this way:

```
xaxp = "n"
```

But it neither works.

The last I have tried is to put the axis by manual, with this function:

```
axis(side= 1, xaxp= xaxpi)
```

But then they appear overhead:

[image]

I would appreciate if someone knows how to solve it.

Comment: Solution: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/250857/funci%C3%B3n-r-hdr-den-problema-con-intervalos-en-el-eje-x